Spring cloud stream binder kafka test slice
I can't find all classes needed to produce and consume messages using spring cloud stream binder kafka without bootstrapping the whole Spring Context.
I use the following spring cloud starter:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

I was able to launch the application using this configuration, but without being able to consume kafka messages:
    @ActiveProfiles( "test" )
    @SpringBootTest( classes = {        
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.simple.SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class,
    
            org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration.class,
    
            org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration.class,
    
            org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.ContextFunctionCatalogAutoConfiguration.class,
            org.springframework.cloud.function.cloudevent.CloudEventsFunctionExtensionConfiguration.class,
            org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.KotlinLambdaToFunctionAutoConfiguration.class,
            org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.FunctionsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
            org.springframework.cloud.function.observability.ObservationAutoConfiguration.class,
    
            org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindersHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class,
            org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ChannelsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
            org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
            org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceConfiguration.class,
            org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BinderFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
            org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration.class,
    
            org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.config.ExtendedBindingHandlerMappingsProviderConfiguration.class,
    ....
    })
    @EmbeddedKafka
    class SpringCloudStreamKafkaTest {
    //....
    

}
What auto-configuration classes are needed to test spring cloud stream binder kafka?
